# ProgressBar looks different in different activities

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have two activities, and a `ProgressBar` in each. The part of xml in first activity:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_pb_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/result"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/un_tv" />
```

and it looks like:

[image: First Progress bar]

with the two overlapping circles.

The second one's xml:

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_pb_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

And it looks like

[image: Second Progress Bar]

With only one circle.

Both are pretty much the same, both java files of the activities have `android.widget.ProgressBar` imported. How do I get them to look the same? Preferably like the first one?

Comment: make sure you are not using different themes for you Activities inside you `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @SMR I've not specified any theme for any activity in the android manifest. The application tag in which all activity tags are present has an attribute android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: have you customized it using java code?

Comment: @SMR only used pb.setVisibility(View.GONE) and pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE). Other than that, nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ProgressBar` is just the same. The difference is due to the `background`.

In the first case, since the background is not **white** or **gray**, both circles of the `ProgressBar` are visible. In the second case, since the background is **white**, the **white** circle of the ProgressBar is not visible.

You can varify this by changing the background color in the second activity.

Comment: Wow I didn't think that would happen. I just changed the background on the second one to coloured and it looks like the first one. Thanks!